# How to force preload of my website (or add a loading screen that would do the same)

Tags: javascript, html

I have to scroll down my webiste to make my background images appear and also it takes a while, how could i fix that by javascript by adding some kind of loading screen before displaying whole website

here's my website: https://donajsky.5v.pl/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please visit the help centre and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You can create something that loads the page on the background and show the user a loading screen, but that might not be a good idea in terms of user experience and SEO.

I´d suggest to improve loading speeds by reducing the size of your images (space6.jpg for example is over 3 MB) so that your site loads quicker.

You can also take a look at lazy loading. The page then only loads the visible images. When the user scrolls down, more images are downloaded in the background. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/Lazy_loading for example.